# How to perform edit and delete operation using jquery

Tags: jquery, object, save, edit, delete-row

i can able to add details and delete also. When i click delete button the table row is delete and not in object, I want when I click delete button the details is delete in object also and i added edit and save button when i edit a particular row and give save option, the new data will display in object and table.

```
<div id="add" class="addDiv" style="display:none">
        <span>Add Details</span>
        <div><span>Name</span><input id="nm" type="text"/></div>
        <div><span>Field1</span><input id="f1" type="text"/></div>
        <div><span>Feild2</span><input id="f2" type="text"/></div>
            <div>
                <input id="adbut" type="button" value="Add"/>
                <input id="cbut" type="button" value="cancel"></input>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input id="crt" type="button" value="create"/>
        <input id="obj" type="button" value="emp obj"/>
    </div>
    <div id="dtaListing">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Name</td><td>Item1</td><td>Item2</td><td>Action</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table" id="list" style="display:none">
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
    <div id="edit" class="ed" style="display:none">
        <span>Edit Details</span>
        <div><span>Name</span><input id="nam" type="text"/></div>
        <div><span>Item1</span><input id="i1" type="text"/></div>
        <div><span>Item2</span><input id="i2" type="text"/></div>
            <div>
                <input id="sv" type="button" value="Save"/>
                <input id="cn" type="button" value="cancel"></input>
            </div>
    </div>

    .show {display:block}
    .hide {display:none}
    .addDiv{position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;border:1px solid #B6A6A6;background-color:#FFF;}
    .table{width:100%;border:1px solid #B6A6A6;background-color:#FFF;}
    .table td{border:1px solid #B6A6A6;};
    .ed{position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;border:1px solid #B6A6A6;background-color:#FFF;}


$("#adbut").click(function(){
    var nm = $("#nm").val();
    var f1 = $("#f1").val();
    var f2 = $("#f2").val();
    if(nm && nm!=""){
        var nEmpObj = {}
        nEmpObj.name = nm;
        nEmpObj.f1 = f1;
        nEmpObj.f2 = f2;
        fArr.push(nEmpObj);
        $("#list").append(constList(nEmpObj));
        $("#list").show();
        $("#add").hide();
    }

 });

$("#cbut").click(function(){
    $("#add").hide();
});

$("#crt").click(function(){
    $("#add").show();
});
$("#obj").click(function(){
    alert(JSON.stringify(fArr));
});
$('.del').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
$("#et").live('click',function(){
       var name=$(row.children().get(0)).text(),
        item1=$(row.children().get(1)).text(),
        item2=$(row.children().get(2)).text();
    nam.value=name;
    i1.value=item1;
    i2.value=item2;
          $("#edit").show(); 

});


$("#cn").click(function(){
    $("#edit").hide();
});
function get_data()
{

}
var fArr = [];

var constList = function(dta){
    return $("<tr><td>"+dta.name+"</td><td>"+dta.f1+"</td><td>"+dta.f2+"</td><td><button class  = del>Delete</button><button id = et >Edit</button></td></tr>")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do somethig like this. This is just a glimpse on how you can achieve it

```
var currentItemIndex = //Get it your way

for (var i = currentItemIndex;i<$("td:last").getIndex();i++) //getIndex is a custom method to return the index value of last item
{
    //increment index by accessing element as $(td:nth-child(i))
}
```

**EDIT:**

Modify your `$('.del').live('click',function(){` as:

```
$('#list .del').live('click',function(){
    delete fArr[$(this).parent().parent().index()];
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Hope this solves your problem. Google has a lot of solutions to remove `null` from your json object.

Comment: Thank you Saksham i'll send my link what i did upto  now. I want to perform edit and delete operation. I created object and i can store values if i press empobj button i can see my records in table and object, now i wanna do same as for edit and delete. if i click edit and delete button the operation should perform in both table and object

Comment: @ Saksham  yeah it is working good, but only the table row is getting delete not in object. You can see my link after delete row when i click empobj button it shows deleted data

Comment: @Mahi after delete, the object is also getting deleted when you use my updated method.

Comment: @Mahi did it help?? I modified your fiddle and delete was working fine for me

Comment: yeah it is getting delete in table alone not in object

Comment: Hi, now i can make edit and store data in table as well as object. But, delete operation working in table and fails in object.You can see whether the data deleted in object using empobj button i'll send my link, incase delete perform in object, click update button in JSfiddle and sent to me. This is my link http://jsfiddle.net/N4N2x/56/

Comment: @Mahi ohh i had accidently posted the wrong code. see http://jsfiddle.net/N4N2x/63/ and my edit. Google has a lot of solutions to remove null from your json object.

Answer (score 0):

You better of using a jQuery plug-in already implementing the full CRUD operations than inventing the wheel again, take a look at jTable: http://plugins.jquery.com/jTable/

Cheers,